# How to find a family's Kuladevata when all known sources have failed?

Tags: gods, bhakti

A lot of Hindu families these days don't know who their Kuladevata is. How can one find out, if there is no information available online, in the community, and if the elders in the family are not alive or don't know?

Comment: I dont remember it, but there is a solution: to choose a certain god (as kuladevat) if kuladevata is not known. Also, I dont think there is way to search if all available ways are closed.

Comment: To get a kuladevi (Since I dont have scriptural proof I will comment): From your main village list out all Main temples of devi in range of 200 km, make paper chits of each. Then on Friday call a Kumarika (a girl child less than age 9) perform puja of her (that's fulfilling her with a meal, giving gifts etc) and ask her to pick up a paper chit. The temple that comes is your kuladevi.

Comment: @Proxy  Thanks for your response. I'm not sure if the rules allow me to comment on my personal situation, but I will. My ancestors moved from one village to another in a different state many generations ago. So we have no idea which village to use as the reference point. Is there any other ritual for this?

Comment: Either use last known village or: On Friday, keep 11 vida (betel leaves) and 11 suparies on it. First is Ganapati, 2 is kuladevta, 3 is kulapurush, 4 is vastupurush, 5 is vastudevta and the rest 6 are kuladevis. Perform puja of these all suparies (I.e. giving halad, kumkum, akshat, flowers, coins and some nevidya some sweet etc). Do this for ×3 fri. On next Fri call a married women and fill Ot (ओटी) of her.

Comment: On the last, perfom a standerd meal as done on festival as nevidya. This concludes the 3 fridays. You may call your close one in families. This was given in a video suggested by one of my family member : https://youtu.be/ct__Ab2LV38 
Ot (ओटी): women of house apply halid, kumkum and give a piece of cloth along with raw rice. And touch the feet of her as if she is devi. This is done without even knowing kuladevta, if its known upto some extent you may arbitrarily name the rest 6 on behalf of them. **The best is to ask a local Pandit, for solution**

Comment: @Proxy- Thanks for sharing the link. I'm marathi too, I will share this with my family. Really appreciate all your guidance.